# Using iFrame local scripts within an iFrame requires `top` or `parent`?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

As the title suggests, does anyone know how to eliminate the need for `top` or `parent` in iFrame localized scripts?

In the screenshot below, I get a "not defined" error unless I add `top or parent` as a prefix to my function call.

`test();` does NOT work

`top.test();` works OK

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have some errors in different part of your code which you didn't post here (actually you didn't post ANY code, only meaningless screenshot of DOM inspector...). This should work just fine without `top` and `parent`.